# Wordpress - Woocomerce archive page show brand before title

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-wordpress-pages

I have an eCommerce site, building with woo-commerce, and I installed a plugin that shows the brand of the product.

In single product page, I manage to put the brand name (text) before the title.
but in the shop main page, I'm trying to put it under the thumbnail and it does not work.

This is the action loop that I found in plugin files:

```js
add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', array($this, 'show_brands_in_loop'));
```

and I tried to change it to every loop and it didn't work I tried:

```js
woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title
```

and:

```js
woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title
```

**nothing work I'm trying to place this here (the green line):**

[image]

Comment: Which version of Woocommerce are you running?

Comment: WordPress 5.4.2
WooCommerce 4.3.1
I can update.. why are you asking>

Comment: It's important for people answering to know what versions of software you are running, because that might affect the answer they give (e.g. something might be possible in one version but not another).